# solarized color theme not working properly in tmux

Tags: vim, tmux

I'm on Ubuntu 14.04, I installed:

1. konsole
2. tmux 1.9.6
3. vim 7.4.52

When I directly start vim in konsole, it's working fine.
But if I start vim in tmux, there's some coloring issues which is really annoying, please see below screenshot.

here's the part of the color setting in my vimrc:

```
set background=light
let g:solarized_termcolors=256
set t_Co=256
colorscheme solarized
```

where's the problem? Could anyone help here?

[image]

Comment: What is your `$TERM` environment variable set to when you are in tmux? Also does your tmux config have `set -g default-terminal ____` specfied? For reference my tmux.conf has `set -g default-terminal xterm` and my ~/.bashrc has `export TERM="xterm-256color"`.

Comment: I finally got solution from the answer of this SO question:
http://superuser.com/a/562423/243529

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solution from this answer of another SO question:
https://superuser.com/a/562423/243529